# RegEx and IIS - insecure content not loaded after redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I am trying to write an SSL redirect rules for IIS with url rewrite 2.0, inside MVC. The idea is, that a visitor should be redirected to https whenever he/she tries to access a sensitive area (f.e. login and signup forms), and if he goes to any other page, the reverse takes place: https requests get redirected to http. What I have done so far:

```
<rule name="Use SSL for private pages" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="[.*/]*(user|signup)" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" 
          appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<rule name="Don't use SSL for non-private pages" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="[.*/]*(user|signup)" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="ON" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}"
          appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The problem is: When I load secure area, browsers refuse to load insecure content (javascripts and images). I did not experiance this problem before adding rule "Don't use SSL for non-private pages".

Can anyone help me solve this or suggest some other way to do it? It should, however, be using web.config and url rewrite

Comment: I take it the assets your SSL pages reference are relative urls? i.e. without the `http://mysite.com/...`

Comment: They are relative urls, however after your question I noticed, that the page, while being in ssl mode, requests resources through non-ssl connection. My guess is that those requests get overwritten by the second rule and the browser blocks the insecure content. Still no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

After some wall head-banging, I discovered, that adding condition helped. To be more precises, I allowed 2'nd rule to take place ONLY if requested file extension is NOT css or js